# Getting StackOverflowError when trying to use Quick Sort method

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Here is what my quick sort looks like:

```
public int[] arrayToSort = {5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 9};
...
private void quickSort(int left, int right) {
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int pivot = arrayToSort[(left + right - left) / 2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arrayToSort[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while(arrayToSort[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if(i <= j) {
            swap(arrayToSort, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if(left < j) {
        quickSort(left, j);
    }
    if(i <right) {
        quickSort(i, right);
    }
}

private void swap(int[] arrayToSort, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arrayToSort[i];
    arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[j];
    arrayToSort[j] = temp;
}
```

I'm really not sure why I get a StackOverflowError in the first line of the quickSort(..) method. What is the problem? Not sure how I could use the debugger to help me here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think you _shouldn't_ get a `StackOverflowError`?

Comment: "Not sure how I could use the debugger to help me here." Well you could step into and through your code to work out what's going on... I'm sure it's only blowing up after several recursive calls...

Comment: Double check your exit condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is almost certainly wrong.

```
(left + right - left) / 2
```

is the same as

```
 right / 2
```

most likely this should be

```
 left + (right - left) / 2
```

or possibly even

```
 (left + right) >>> 1
```

as it is in the JDK.

> Not sure how I could use the debugger to help me here.

In the debugger it would have been harder to see that the `mid` was being calculated incorrectly without putting it into a variable or in an expression.

Comment: Ah snap - I can see that now through my debugger, guess I'll need to get more familiar with it. Thanks.

Comment: @eyesenberg in this case, using the debugger is not so obvious as just reading the code. ;)